# PHP код в переменной как обычный текст

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сделать автоматическое создание страниц и при создании записываю туда небольшой PHP код:

```
$fp = fopen($file, "w"); 
        fwrite($fp, "
                <? $arr = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                    $resArr = explode('/', $arr);
                    //var_dump($resArr);
                    $str = '';
                    $length = count($resArr);
                ?>
                <div> ...
              ");
```

Проблема в том что из-за кучи скобок и PHP кода, ругается обработчик. Можно сделать так чтобы обработчик воспринимал этот код, как простой текст?

Comment: [`nowdoc`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) вам в помощь

Answer (score 1):

> **Nowdoc ¶**
>
> `Nowdoc` - это то же самое для строк в одинарных кавычках, что и `heredoc`
>   для строк в двойных кавычках. `Nowdoc` похож на `heredoc`, но внутри него
>   не осуществляется никаких подстановок. ***Эта конструкция идеальна для
>   внедрения PHP-кода или других больших блоков текста без необходимости
>   его экранирования.*** В этом он немного похож на SGML-конструкцию
>   `<![CDATA[ ]]>` тем, что объявляет блок текста, не предназначенный для
>   обработки.
>
> `Nowdoc` указывается той же последовательностью `<<<`, что используется в
>   `heredoc`, но последующий за ней идентификатор заключается в одинарные
>   кавычки, например, `<<<'EOT'`. Все условия, действующие для `heredoc`
>   идентификаторов также действительны и для `nowdoc`, особенно те, что
>   относятся к закрывающему идентификатору.

*[© документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)*

Подробнее:

- [`heredoc` синтаксис](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)
- [`nowdoc` синтаксис](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

Для вашего примера:

```
$content = <<<'CODE'
    <? $arr = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
       $resArr = explode('/', $arr);
       //var_dump($resArr);
       $str = '';
       $length = count($resArr);
    ?>
    <div> ...
CODE; 
$fp = fopen($file, "w"); 
fwrite($fp, $content);
```

Однако, поскольку данный код вы планируете вставлять во множество файлов, то лучше подключите его через `include`, что позволить избежать проблем, когда понадобится внести изменения во все нагенерированное.